# Is there a way to send outputs to an Xbox like a controller?

Tags: c#, windows, joystick, xbox-one

I have a really old joystick designed for Windows 95/98. Obviously, it is not supported on xbox one however I have seen that you can make them work on Windows 10. Is there any way to connect my laptop to my Xbox and simulate one of the sticks? I am by no means an expert but I have a small knowledge of c#.

Comment: There was a project called x360ce which was supposed to let you do this for XBox 360. https://www.x360ce.com